Save Object file (executable file exe) to a predefined folder
I have manually inserted this file “ABC.exe” as an Object in excel workbook in sheet name e.g “Board”. 
In NameBox the Object has name Object 1 and in Formula Bar  =EMBED("Packager Shell Object","") 
I can manually right-click on the cited object and choose Copy and then Paste on a predefined folder without any issue or warning message. 
I need to automate the process of (Copy and Paste) using VBA. 
This code copy the OLeObject to Clipboard successfully: 
Sub Copy_OleObject_to_Clipboard()
   Dim ws As Worksheet:  Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim ole As OLEObject
     Set ole = ws.OLEObjects(1)
       ole.Copy
End Sub

Indeed, I also have tried ChatGPT , But none of his answers have worked correctly.

If you succeed in performing this copy operation, how are you going to paste the copied file to a folder using VBA?

Please, try the next solution. I adapted a piece of code returning embedded pdf files and maybe some comments remained related to its previous scope.

After embedding the EXE files use 'Alt Text' from the right click  object context menu (formatObject...) , and place there the EXE file name.

The workbook where from to be extracted embedded EXE files, must be closed. The following code warns about it if you do not take care...

Since, as stated above, the workbook having embedded exe files must be closed, the next code must be copied in a xlsm, xlsb, xlsa file and run it from there. Basically, it saves a copy of the workbook, but with zip extension (in fact workbook type xlsx, xlsm, xlsa etc. are such archives containing many xml files and objects. The code firstly extracts the files from archive \xl\worksheets, processes them to extract a logical association between the bin files in \xl\embeddings and the EXE name extracted from worksheets xml files. Then, it binary open the found bin files, and processes them to become correct EXE files.

Please, create a Public variable on top of a standard module (in the declarations area):


   Public ExpArr()


Now, copy the next code in a standard module:

Sub ExtractEmbeddedEXEFiles() 
    Dim retFolder As String, embWB As String, zipName As String, oShell As Object, arrO, i As Long
    
    retFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Extracted Embeded EXE files" 'folder where to process and return extracted exe files
    embWB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\EXE Embedded wb.xlsm" 'wb containing embedded exe file(s) full name
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\EXE Embedded wb.xlsm"
    zipName = left(embWB, InStrRev(embWB, ".")) & "zip"
     
     If Dir(retFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then 'if the folder where to save EXE files does not exist
        MkDir retFolder                                      'it is created
     End If


    'Deleting any previously created files, if any:
    On Error Resume Next
      Kill zipName
      Kill retFolder & "\*.*"
      Kill retFolder & "\_rels\*.*"
      RmDir retFolder & "\_rels\"
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Copy/rename the Excel file changing extension to zip:
    On Error Resume Next
       FileCopy embWB, zipName
       If Err.number = 70 Then        'error in case of workbook being open:
            Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
            MsgBox "Please, close the workbook where from the embedded EXE files to be extracted." & vbCrLf & _
                           "A zipped copy cannot be created...", vbInformation, "Need to close the workbook": Exit Sub
       End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim flsWsh As Object, fileNameInZip As Variant
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    Set flsWsh = oShell.NameSpace(oShell.NameSpace((zipName)).Items.item(("xl\worksheets")))
    For Each fileNameInZip In oShell.NameSpace(flsWsh).Items
            oShell.NameSpace((retFolder)).CopyHere _
                    oShell.NameSpace(flsWsh).Items.item(CStr(fileNameInZip))
    Next
    
    getOLEObjSheetsREL retFolder 'build the array which matches any .bin oleObject with the extracted EXE name
   
    For i = 0 To UBound(ExpArr) 'copy the bin file in a separate place
        arrO = Split(ExpArr(i), "|") 'split the matching array elements by "|" to extract bin name in relation with EXE name
        oShell.NameSpace((retFolder)).CopyHere oShell.NameSpace((zipName)).Items.item("xl\embeddings\" & arrO(0))
        
        ReadAndWriteExtractedBinFile_Exe retFolder & "\" & arrO(0), retFolder, CStr(arrO(1))
    Next i
    
    On Error Resume Next 'clear the working folder, to remain only extracted exe files
      Kill zipName
      Kill retFolder & "\*.bin"
      Kill retFolder & "\*.xml"
      Kill retFolder & "\_rels\*.*"
      RmDir retFolder & "\_rels\"
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    MsgBox "Ready..."
    shell "explorer.exe" & " " & retFolder, vbNormalFocus
End Sub

Sub ReadAndWriteExtractedBinFile_Exe(s As String, TmpPath, Optional pdfName As String = "")
    Dim byteFile As Long, byt As Byte, fileName As String, firstByte As Long, lastByte As Long
    Dim MyAr() As Byte, NewAr() As Byte, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    byteFile = FreeFile:  j = 1
    Dim fLen As Long: fLen = FileLen(s)
    ReDim MyAr(1 To fLen + 1)
    Open s For Binary Access Read As byteFile 'Open the bin file
        Do While Not EOF(byteFile) 'loop untill the last line (count the file bytes)
            Get byteFile, , byt
            MyAr(j) = byt:  j = j + 1
            If j > 7 Then
              If Hex(MyAr(j - 4)) = "4D" And Hex(MyAr(j - 3)) = "5A" And _
                           Hex(MyAr(j - 2)) = 90 And MyAr(j - 1) = 0 Then
                   firstByte = j - 4: ' first byte to be used in the returned byte array
              End If

              If MyAr(j - 6) = 0 And MyAr(j - 5) = 0 And MyAr(j - 4) = 0 And _
                    Hex(MyAr(j - 3)) = 43 And MyAr(j - 2) = 0 And Hex(MyAr(j - 1)) = "3A" Then
                    lastByte = j - 2: Exit Do 'last byte to be used
              End If
            End If
        Loop
    Close byteFile
    
    Dim oStream As Object 'solution to speed up writing the binary array...
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    
    'build the correct byte array without bytes up to exe file real start:
    ReDim NewAr(1 To lastByte - firstByte + 1)
    k = 1
    For j = firstByte To lastByte
        NewAr(k) = MyAr(j):  k = k + 1
    Next j
    oStream.Write NewAr
    'byteFile = FreeFile

    'Set the exe file to be saved name:
    If pdfName = "" Then 'if no pdfName parameter, it builds a unique name:
        fileName = TmpPath & "\" & Format(Now, "ddmmyyhhmmss") & ".exe"
    Else
       fileName = TmpPath & "\" & pdfName  'this solution uses only the extracted (from OLEObject) name
    End If
    'Write the new (exe) binary file:
    If isArrLoaded(NewAr()) Then 'only for EXE (bin) embedded files:
        oStream.SaveToFile fileName, 2 ' 2 to overWrite
        oStream.Close
    Else
        'If by mistake a not appropriate bin file has been choosen:
        Debug.Print "The object is not of exe type..." 'theoretically, this line should never be reached
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub getOLEObjSheetsREL(strPath As String)
   Dim patt As String: patt = "oleObject\d{1,3}.bin"
   Dim strFold As String, strFile As String, strText As String
   Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, arrOLE, arrOLEC(1), arrTot, i As Long
   
   strFold = strPath & "\_rels\" 'copied folder (from archive) keeping sheets and OLEObjects information
   
   ReDim arrTot(0)
   strFile = Dir(strFold & "*.rels")
   Do While strFile <> "" 'iterate between all existing files
         Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
         Set ts = fso.getFile(strFold & strFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
              strText = ts.ReadAll  'read their content
         ts.Close
         arrOLE = getOLEObj(strText, patt) 'extract an array linking OLEObject to EXE file name(s)
         
         If arrOLE(0) <> "" Then
            arrOLEC(0) = left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 5): arrOLEC(1) = arrOLE
            BubbleSort arrOLEC(1) 'sort the array
            arrTot(i) = arrOLEC: i = i + 1: ReDim Preserve arrTot(i)
         End If
         strFile = Dir()
    Loop
    ReDim Preserve arrTot(i - 1)
    getOLEObjects arrTot, strPath 'returning an array linking the bin object to EXE file(s) to be saved file  name
End Sub

Function getOLEObj(strTxt As String, strPatt As String) As Variant
    Dim objOccurr As Object, objOcc, arr, k As Long

     With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
         .Global = True            'Get all matches.
         .pattern = strPatt        'Search for any string that contains the pattern entered in quotes. .
         If .TEST(strTxt) Then
            Set objOccurr = .Execute(strTxt)
            ReDim arr(objOccurr.count - 1)
            For Each objOcc In objOccurr
                arr(k) = objOcc: k = k + 1
            Next
            getOLEObj = arr
        Else
            getOLEObj = Array("")
        End If
   End With
End Function

Private Sub getOLEObjects(arrOLE As Variant, strPath As String)
   Dim strFile As String, strText As String
   Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, j As Long
   Dim arr, frstTxt As String, el, i As Long, strName As String, PrID As String
   Dim k As Long: ReDim ExpArr(100)
   Const strObj As String = "oleObject"
   
   For j = 0 To UBound(arrOLE)
         strFile = strPath & "\" & arrOLE(j)(0)
         Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
         Set ts = fso.getFile(strFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
              strText = ts.ReadAll
        ts.Close
        
        arr = extractBetweenChars(strText, "<oleObject progId=", "<\/mc:Fallback>")
          
        For Each el In arr
              strName = extractBetweenChars(CStr(el), "altText=""", """ r:id")(0)
              PrID = extractBetweenChars(CStr(el), """", """")(0)

              If PrID = "Packager Shell Object" Then i = i + 1 'alt raspuns pentru exe
              If strName <> "" Then
                   If InStr(strName, ".exe") > 0 Then 'for exe files
                          ExpArr(k) = strObj & i & ".bin" & "|" & strName: k = k + 1
                   End If
              End If
        Next
  Next j
  
  'keep only the elements having values:
  If k > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve ExpArr(k - 1)
  Else
       Erase ExpArr
 End If
End Sub

Private Function extractBetweenChars(prevString As String, startCh As String, endCh As String) As Variant
     Dim objOccurr As Object, objOcc, arr, k As Long

     With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
         .Global = True                                   'Get all matches.
         .pattern = startCh & "((.|\n)*?)" & endCh        'Search for any string that contains the pattern entered in quotes. .
         'if boolglobal then extractbetweenchars =
         If .TEST(prevString) Then
            Set objOccurr = .Execute(prevString)
            ReDim arr(objOccurr.count - 1)
            For Each objOcc In objOccurr
                arr(k) = objOcc.subMatches(0): k = k + 1
                'arr(k) = Replace(Replace(objOcc, startCh, ""), Replace(endCh, "\", ""), ""): k = k + 1
            Next
            extractBetweenChars = arr
        Else
            'Debug.Print "Not matched"
            extractBetweenChars = Array("")
        End If
   End With
End Function

Private Function isArrLoaded(arr() As Byte) As Boolean
    If Not Not arr() Then isArrLoaded = True
End Function

Private Sub BubbleSort(arr)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i) > arr(j) Then
                temp = arr(i): arr(i) = arr(j)
                arr(j) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Please, test it and send some feedback.
I tested on two embedded EXE files and it was able to return them. I did not test it extensively, so I need your feedback. I tried finding HEX elements to extract only the necessary part from the bin files in order to rebuild the EXE file.
It worked in my those two cases...
Since is a big code and some Sub(s), Functions exist in different modules I maybe missed something. I do not think so, but it may not be impossible...
Edited:
Please, test this simpler way able to extract the embedded object as it was embedded. I mean, even without extension...
Even if I think that this method will not be considered by your antivirus as a threat. Is looks as a simple copy - paste action. But this is just a supposition.

Please copy the next API function on top of a standard module (in the declarations area) of the workbook containing the embedded exe file:

Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long


In the same standard module, please paste the next code:

Sub Extract_All_EmbededObjectsFromClipboard() 'It works...
  Dim strPath As String: strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Embedded Objects" 'the folder where to return the extracted file
  
  If Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then 'if the folder where to save EXE files does not exist
      MkDir strPath                       'it is created
  End If
  
  Dim oleObj As OLEObject, boolOK As Boolean
  For Each oleObj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    oleObj.Copy
    boolOK = EmbededObjectFromClipboard(strPath)
  Next oleObj
  
  RenameEXEFiles strPath
  
  If boolOK Then
        Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & strPath, vbNormalFocus
  End If
  
End Sub

Sub RenameEXEFiles(strPath As String) ' it works only for extracted EXE files (to place ".exe" if it is missing
 Dim fileName As String
 fileName = Dir(strPath & "\*.*")
 Do While fileName <> ""
    Debug.Print fileName
    If Right(fileName, 4) <> ".exe" Then
        If FileExists(strPath & "\" & fileName & ".exe") Then
            Name strPath & "\" & fileName As strPath & "\" & fileName & "_.exe"
        Else
            Name strPath & "\" & fileName As strPath & "\" & fileName & ".exe"
        End If
    End If
    fileName = Dir
 Loop
End Sub
Private Function FileExists(ByVal fname As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
      FileExists = ((GetAttr(fname) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)
    On Error GoTo 0: Err.Clear
End Function

Function EmbededObjectFromClipboard(DestinationFolder As String) As Boolean
    EmbededObjectFromClipboard = False
    If Not CBool(IsClipboardFormatAvailable(49162)) Then Exit Function '49162 is Format ID for Embeded Object!
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(CVar(DestinationFolder)).Self.InvokeVerb "Paste"
    EmbededObjectFromClipboard = True
End Function

And run TestEmbededObjectFromClipboard. It will copy the "Object `" embedded file to the nominated folder. Even if does not have any extension. It looks copying binary...
The updated code add ".exe" to the extracted files, if they do not have it... But is should be obvious that it works only if you try extracting EXE files. Without extension there is no VBA method to understand what kind of file is it about. Or, it is very complicated (binary reading the file and search for some markers...)...
Edited again:
A way to return all files from a folder is the next one:
Private Function getAllFiles(strFold As String, Optional strExt As String = "*.*") As Variant
    Dim arrD
    arrD = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strExt & """ /b").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    arrD(UBound(arrD)) = "@@##": arrD = Filter(arrD, "@@##", False) 'remove the last (empty) array elem
    getAllFiles = arrD
End Function

'a sub to test it:
Sub testGetAllFiles()
 Debug.Print Join(getAllFiles(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"), vbCrLf)
End Sub


1- If extension of files is hidden then I got (Run-time error '53': File not found) at this line Set ts = fso.getFile(strFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).
2- If extension of files is visible then I got (Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range) at this line For i = 0 To UBound(ExpArr) 'copy the bin file in a separate place.
3- Anyhow I do not prefer to run the macro towards a closed workbook (It is against my aim for full Automation)

@Peace 1. Didn't you ask about "executable file exe"? Each type of embedded objects should be treat/processed according to their type which is given by the file extension... Is the extension missing in Alt Text property, too? It maybe can be solved in this way (if I will be able to somehow identify the embedded file type), but you did not ask about that! 2. When stopped on error, moving the cursor over ExpArr what does it display? 3. Where in your question did you specify "It is against my aim for full Automation"? It probably, can be done so, too, using saving As Copy.

@Peace Can you share the respective workbook, to find a way for extracting your real embedded exe file?

@Peace Please, test the updated answer. It is able to also process Exe files without extension, but in the object Alt Text property you need to writhe the exe name you want, WITH EXE extension. Please, test this. It will extract Rufus. Once, named as rufus-2.11.exe and second file as R-2.11.exe. But if you will often play with the workbook and the same files your antivirus will detect something abnormal and it will maybe block them... Please, send some feedback after testing it.

also I have updated my question with a simple code to copy the OLeObject to windows clipboard , But the problem is it seems VBA not able to deal with object inside clipboard ( it do well if it was text only)

@Peace I know how to extract ranges, to paste files, but I do not know how to deal with such bin files. I already tried this approach, but I am abroad in vacation and no enough availability. I will try again tomorrow, if somebody else will not solve it. But didn't the updated code do the job? Didn't you test the wb I shared? If tested didn't it work as you need? This was what you asked commenting on my answer...

I tried your latest update and the same error still exists, 1- If extension of files is hidden in Windows explorer then I got (Run-time error '53': File not found) at this line Set ts = fso.getFile(strFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2). 2- If extension of files is visible then I got (Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range) at this line For i = 0 To UBound(ExpArr , I have sent the workbook to your email (including the code of exe)

@Peace Did you test the workbook I shared? If so, couldn't it return the embedded exe files? Did you receive any error trying THAT workbook? I am at airport and I cannot test anything...

No, sorry indeed I didn't notice that you already shared a link for a workbook, I tried your last update on my test workbook ( whom I sent it's link to your email)

@Peace I am at home now and downloaded the workbook you sent. I can see that you do not use the updated code I supplied and you did not follow what I wrote to the first issue: "After embedding the EXE files use 'Alt Text' from the right click object context menu (formatObject...) , and place there the EXE file name.". I will copy the updated code, write the exe file name in the Format Object... - Alt Text of the right click context menu and try running the code.

@Peace I found a missing (If) code line (which could immediately be discovered if you would test the above code), copied it in your file and did what I wrote above to be writen (related to Object Alt Text...) and it worked as it should. Please, download and test it from here, then send some feedback. Did you test the workbook I sent yesterday? It contains and it is able to extract an EXE file using its real name (Rufus) and the same file without extension, but in Alt Text object property having the complete exe file to be saved name.

I downloaded your updated file and it works correctly to extract the embedded file. Now your code needs a little enhancement, like delete EXE Embedded wb.xlsm as it is not needed any more, also (to avoid hyper-sensitivity of my antivirus Kaspersky towards embedded files) is it possible If I manually embedded my file without extension .exe and then rename the extracted file and re-add extension .exe again.

@Peace Deleting the workbook copy is simple, I did not focus on such an issue... The code is able to overwrite it, in case of multiple tests. Of course, I can do it and I am sure you can do it, too. Now, I am not sure I understand second part of your comment... 1. You can manually embed an exe file without extension. 2. I am afraid you cannot save a file without extension. You can obtain such one, only by deletion if its extension. 3. But you can save the file without extension using what name you need, but containing the necessary extension. Did you test the workbook I sent yesterday?

in fact I have test only your latest file https://easyupload.io/jfzwa7

@Peace Besides that, I am trying now (theoretically) the simpler way, I mean to save the embedded object from clipboard. As I said in one of my previous comments, I know extracting from clipboard ranges and files (of different types) and now I am making experiments to determine the embedded object Format ID. I think it is probable to find a solution for this way, too... This looks as a bigger challenge for me.

@Peace To test the first one go above 10 comments and download it from there (this)...

@Peace Please, test the new version able to copy and extract from clipboard the embedded files. You can download from here the updated workbook able to extract all embedded files, even without extension. The workbook contains now two such exe files (in fact, the same file... Once with extension and second time without). Please, send some feedback after testing it.

I downloaded your latest workbook (from your last comment), both codes works correctly, especially the edited code to retrieve the files from windows clipboard. Please, is it possible to add the extension (.exe) back to the file using VBA on the same code

@Peace It should be possible but I don't know if it is possible to preliminarily extract the object name from clipboard. If you intend to extract only EXE files it would be simple to do it at the end, for all files in the extraction folder.

I mean to check the extracted file and no need to check clipboard

@Peace If it is a single extracted file it would be simple, but trying to extract many files, you can not know, or it is very complicated to extract from clipboard each such file name, would need to do it for all. Anyhow, I will adapt the above code to do it... I used to be able to extract the file name from clipboard (using GetClipboardData API), but it does not work anymore (in Windows 11)...

After I tried your code ( and works correctly) then I closed my workbook , But after that when I have opened the same workbook again I got a strange message “Invalid data format” and the title of the message box is ”Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications” , and I cannot deal with the workbook anymore , I tried your code on a another new Workbook and the same issue “Invalid data format” when opening the workbook ,Note: I am using Office 2016 32 bit on windows 10 64 Bit

@Peace Not sure I understand what you mean... Does the reopened workbook raise that error by itself when it is loaded, or if you try running its code? The code is designed for 64 bit. The single part caring about it is IsClipboardFormatAvailable API. May I remotely connect with AnyDesk?

that error happens by itself when the workbook is opened (not run your codes yet) , I have a break after 30 minutes and can connect to my laptop

@Peace When that error is raised isn't the line of that API declaration (IsClipboardFormatAvailable) shown with red characters? Except the respective error, isn't the VBE window shown at all?

@Peace Saving again the sent workbook (maybe, with a different name) does it raise the same error when try opening it?

I tried on my own Laptop ( also Office 2016 32Bit and Windows 10 64Bit) , But I did not get the mentioned error and the workbook has opened and closed without any issue

Now I have removed & "\Embedded Objects" to save the exported OleObject on the same folder of Thisworkbook , But I got this error (Run-time error '75': Path/File access error) @ this line Name strPath & "\" & fileName As strPath & "\" & fileName & "_.exe"

@Peace Such an error looks to appear if one of the modules is corrupted. Basically, it happens when Office 365. I read that 2301 build of 365 works and other versions may raise such an error. Try to check the next way: Copy the workbook on desktop and try opening from there. If the same problem, try save it as .xls and see if the problem has gone... What Excel version do you use?

@Peace In my above comment I was talking about the opening error you mentioned before. For the last one, I cannot get you. If you do not show more code I cannot understand where you made a mistake... May I connect to your computer now?

Again to my Work PC , I tried adding any other codes (not yours at all) to a new workbook and I found that  it has been opened and closed without any issue at all. At last I found out the problem (code) that leads to corrupt the workbook and raises “ Invalid data file” , It is Function EmbededObjectFromClipboard(DestinationFolder As String) As Boolean , when I have used all your last code except the mentioned Function then The workbook has opened and closed without any issue at all.

@Peace But that function uses IsClipboardFormatAvailable API, I mentioned above... Please, create a testing sub and write the next code (on separate lines): #If VBA7 Then Debug.Print "VBA7" #End If #If Win64 Then Debug.Print "Win64" #End If. What does it return in Immediate Window?

I tried and got VBA7

@Peace Only "VB7"? Didn't you also get "Win64"? Did you copy and use the part related to Win64?

@Peace If you used also the part related to Win64 and nothing in Immediate Window from that side, try changing the API declaration in Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long and test it. Firstly, does it return the extracted exe files? If so, it probably is the suitable declaration for your installation. If it works without problems I can adapt the code able to deal with both installation cases (32 or 64Bit) (conditional compilation).

@Peace  Practically, when you will change the declaration as suggested above, if compiler does not like it, the declaration code line will be displayed with red fonts and a compiler message warning about the necessity to adapt it at 64Bit...

I tried #If Win64 Then     Debug.Print "Win64" #End If and nothing has been appeared in immediate window

@Peace OK, for such a case I suggested above the way it is good to try the changed API declaration...  Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long

I tried and Unfortunately the same issue

@Peace What do you mean by "the same"? Did it work when you try the code? Did the declaration code line become red? Did the workbook become unusable after saving and restarting? Or what?

declaration code line NOT became red, the workbook became unusable after saving and restarting

@Peace I cannot reproduce this behavior. What Excel version do you use? What build does it have if 365? I made some recommendations in an above comment... It looks to be a corruption related issue. It may happen in some builds of Office 365.

I have consulted ChatGPT for that strange problem, message “Invalid data format” , He adviced me to use Early Binding for Shell and Folder objects by setting the reference to "Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation".
I tried his advice and now your code works correctly as it should and I closed the Workbook and opened many times without any issue.

@Peace Strange, indeed... But it is good to understand that this is strictly related to your Office installation. I asked many times about your Excel version and build but you did not say anything... And did you only added the reference? If so, I would never guess that this can be problematic (for any Excel version).

1- I already mentioned  my (Office and Windows) version on my comments (on this question) two times at least (as I remember ). 2- I still need to save the OLEObject on a predefined explicit folder, e.g. saving oleObj on the same folder where ThisWorkbook exists. I tried modifying to be strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path but I got (Run-time error '75': Path/File access error) at this line Name strPath & "\" & fileName As strPath & "\" & fileName & ".exe" .Note: I have full access to folder where ThisWorkbook exists.

@Peace 1. Yes, I missed that part. That's why I kept asking... 2. I don't know what to say. Try taking the folder ownership. If you are able now for a short connection I can better try understanding what's happening on your computer. It is my first day after vacation and I am very busy, but I can spend 10 - 15 minutes trying to help in this way...

The logic of Sub RenameEXEFiles(strPath As String) is destructive, all the files inside that folder ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Embedded Objects" have been renamed by adding extension (.exe) to it. Anyhow, you have answered my question as it was formulated (Many Thanks) and it is up to you if you wish to find a solution for me regarding that Name issue.

@Peace Yes, it is destructive! So was the logic of my code to work repetitively. You are responsible for the modifications you make... If you would ask me about that, I would analize the involvements and I would warn you about the involvements. As I said, I am very busy in my first day after vacation and not enough time to analyze. I offered myself to remotely connect and In such a case I certainly could se the involvements running the code line by line and see what happens or what may happen. I do not understand what do you mean by Name issue!

@Peace Related to name issue do you want me to adapt the code to allow saving the emebedded exe objects in the folder where the xlsm workbook with embeded objects exists? If yes, it probably, can be possible, but this involves a lot of work and you need to prove why such a requirement is really necessary. I designed the code in that way exactly to avoid keeping a lot of garbage on your HD. The meaning of returning in an additional subfolder was exactly that, to  not interfere with some other files existing there... As I said, I cannot extract the name of the objects.

@Peace If you copy some files in Clipboard, I can return their full name! But for such abstract objects I cannot. I tried it and I couldn't. I do not say that it is impossible, I only say that I could not do it.  If I will have more availability and I will not forget about it I proposed to myself to try harder. But not in the next future and without being sure that I will do it... Only as a challenge.

@Peace I think it can be done in a next step, copying/moving the returned and renamed files (with exe extension) in the folder you need... Would it be convenient? But if there are other files with the same name, it will not be able to copy this ones. The code can warn about them and simple delete them from the initial folder, too...

I have an idea, at beginning of your code I will iterate with all the files on the predefined folder and save it’s full names with extension into an Array, and after you code extract OleObjects and save it on the same predefined folder then I will iterate again with all the files and put into a second Array then compare between them and put the differences into a third Array and rename files inside that Array (if file has no extension ) by adding .exe . I know you are busy ,So I will ask ChatGPT to do it for me.

@Peace This is simple. Obtain the array of files (without iteration) then extract the array of files in the predefined folder and match them with the initial array. If they do not match (erroring) they will be analyzed against having or not any extension... But why do do it in this way, since you can do it as it is done in the above code and finally make another step to move them in the folder you want?

Sorry if this is irrelevant, I remember that you have used a method to extract a cell value from a closed workbook (but I forgot it) I didn't mean using ADO

@Peace For a single cell try using ExecuteExcel4Macro.

@Peace I observed this question two days before and tried reproducing the behavior, to understand what's happening and see if it is something able to solve the issue. But I couldn't. I have Office 2019 and an IMAP account synchronized with the mail server. I am not able to send mails to deleted items. They are simple deleted and the same is done on the mail server. I tried finding a setting to temporarily allow keeping them in the deleted folder but I did not find anything (simple). My Outlook does not even have the Advanced Settings in the Account Settings - Change - More Settings...

@Peace I found something in Control Pannel - Mail, if I remember well, but in the meantime I hade something else to do and I  lost my enthusiasm...
